# Inner product of bosonic coherent states

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, bosons, coherent-states

In the notation of Altland and Simons, we have bosonic coherent state:
$$
|\phi\rangle = \exp \left(\sum_i \phi_i a_i^\dagger\right) |0\rangle.
$$

On page 159, they use $\langle0|\phi\rangle = 1$ while computing the inner product $\langle\theta|\phi\rangle$ of two coherent states. Why is $\langle 0|\phi\rangle = 1$?

Is the reason that
$$
\langle 0|\exp \left(\sum_i \phi_i a_i^\dagger\right) |0\rangle = \langle0| \text{identity} | 0\rangle + \langle0 | \sum_i \phi_i a_i^\dagger | 0 \rangle + \frac{1}{2}\langle0 | \left(\sum_i \phi_i a_i^\dagger\right)^2 | 0 \rangle + \ldots
$$
and that all the terms on the right are zero except the first $\langle0|\text{identity}|0\rangle = 1$?

Comment: Yes. __________

Comment: But why do you post if you know the answer? What would be a good answer? "Yes" is too short.

Comment: Thanks! That's a good point. I spent a long time confused about the reason the inner product is 1, and when I was about to post the question, it was more a random guess because I wanted to show I had thought about it. If you want to post that as the answer, I'd be happy to accept it as an answer.

Comment: "Yes" is too short to be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. $(a^\dagger)^n\vert0\rangle$ is a Fock state with $n$ bosons, ans thus orthogonal to $\vert0\rangle$ for $n>0$.